# Cotangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

We have the sequence
$0 \rightarrow \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^2}\rightarrow3\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-1)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}\rightarrow 0$.

Can we write a exact sequece such that $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ is on the right?

Sorry if the question was not properly written, I'm looking for a exact sequece of the form
$0 \leftarrow \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^2}\leftarrow \bigoplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(a_{1i})\leftarrow \bigoplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(a_{2i})\leftarrow \cdots$ (with all the terms given by sums of line bundles)

If it exists how can I contruct it?

Comment: I think you'll need to give more details to get a good answer; as it stands, the answer is obviously (but unhelpfully) "yes". What kind of terms do you want to allow in the exact sequence?

Comment: Search for "Euler sequence". It is covered, for example, in Hartshorne's book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
0 \to O(-3) \to O(-2)^{\oplus 3} \to \Omega^1 \to 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks. By computing the global sections I guessed it could be that but it could only work if we already knew that there exists a resolution. Why does it exists? Are we using the relation between the tangent and the cotangent? I thought it only worked for cohomologies and not for the sheaves themselves...

Comment: $\Omega^1 = T(-3)$.